# Number of isomorphism classes of subsets of the power set $\mathcal{P}([n])$

Tags: combinatorics

I believe that this should have been studied, so am I asking for some reference or OEIS sequence for the number of isomorphism classes of subsets of the power set $\mathcal{P}([n])$, $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Two families, subsets of the power set, are considered equivalent and then belonging to the same class, if they can be made equal through a permutation of elements: for example $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\} \equiv \{\{b\},\{a,b\}\} \equiv \{\{c\},\{c,d\}\}$.

For example for $\mathcal{P}([1]) = \{\emptyset, \{a\}\}$, we have the following $3$ classes: $\{\emptyset\}$, $\{\{a\}\}$, $\{\emptyset, \{a\}\}$.

For $\mathcal{P}([2]) = \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{a,b\}\}$, we have the following $11$ classes: $\{\emptyset\}$, $\{\{a\}\}$, $\{\emptyset, \{a\}\}$, $\{\{a,b\}\}$, $\{\emptyset, \{a,b\}\}$, $\{\{a\},\{b\}\}$, $\{\emptyset, \{a\},\{b\}\}$, $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$, $\{\emptyset, \{a\},\{a,b\}\}$, $\{\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$, $\{\emptyset, \{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$.

Comment: Wait, so $\{\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$ is different than $\{\{a\},\{b\},\{a,c\}\}$ for example or not? The question is, you need to go from one to another using a bijective function or any function would do?

Comment: Yes they are different because there is no permutation of elements that can give the second family from the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like Burnside lemma. Here is the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A003180) for also considering the empty set.

To find $Fix(\pi )=\{X\in \mathcal{P}([n]):\pi (X)=X\}$ I would go over the fixed points of the permutation itself. There is a formula in that link.